# blok udp 53 traffic to Internet only from lan

Tags: linux, iptables, dnsmasq

i want to block all dns queries from lan to Internet so only server allowed to make dns requests
so i need rule to dns requests from eth0 to Internet allowed, lan to eth1 allowed, but lan to Internet rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try reading the iptables manual?

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i lan -o internet -p tcp --dport 53 -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lan -o internet -p udp --dport 53 -j REJECT
```

Comment: i tried this rule but only with udp and it didn't work

Comment: You should always include in the question what you already tried.